# How to vertically center text in fluid container without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a fluid percentage-based container with a div inside of it containing a title. I would like this title to always remain positioned vertically in the center of this container whenever the browser is resized or the viewport changes. Is it possible to accomplish this vertical repositioning without JavaScript?

```
<div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="meta">Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this ((screnHeight/2)-(metaHeight/2))px?

Comment: Yep, something like that. Basically get the height of the fluid container, get the height of the meta div and position the bottom of the meta to the center of the fluid-container.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my favorite way to do it. I use two helper classes to achive this goal:

```
.valign:after {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
}
.valign > .valigned {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Now when you need to verticaly align something simply add `valign` class to parent and `valigned` to your actualt element. Like this:

```
<div class="fluid-container valign">
    <div class="meta valigned">Title</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/MQMEZ/

Comment: Well `::after` is CSS3 syntax, so you are right, it's better to use it. My bad habbit, I always use `:after` version..

Comment: Yeah, yet I focused on `valigned` - I still don't get it that `::after` generates the pseudoelement inside, not outside.

Comment: Yes, inside. So it looks like `:after` is sibling of the target `valigned` element, and they are both `inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle`. It means that browser will try to align them to match each other. But since pseudo element is 100% streched it forces `valigned` to vertically align too.

Comment: Note that this won't work when the text inside that `valigned` container wraps to more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of height of the "title" tag, or if you can set it with `line-height` and `height`, you can do something like this:

```
.fluid-container {
  position: relative;
}
.fluid-container > .meta {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yjy5C/2/

Comment: Yes. If he can safely assume the title wont wrap to a second line, he can set the height explicitly in the CSS. This is a generally acceptable solution that avoids hackier methods involving `table-` display styles and `vertical-align`

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use `line-height`, `inline-block`, and `vertical-align:middle` to get the desired effect. It works in all decent browsers. (I once found this technique [here](http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/#valhib))

```
.fluid-container {
    line-height: 8em; /* some abundant value, around the max height */
}
.fluid-container > div.meta {
    vertical-align: middle; /* center… */
    display: inline-block; /* …like text */
}
```